# Spymemcached client and time out error

Tags: networking, spymemcached

I am facing a weird problem with spymemcached client. Say I am in a box whose public ip is x and memcache is running in this box, when I run spymemcached client on the same box and connect to memcache using it's ip as x, I get a timeout error. When I replace x as 127.0.0.1 things work fine. At the same time, if I run the code from a different box and connect to the memcache box as x, things work fine. What is happening here?